# Simple Visual Basic program having trouble?

Tags: vb.net

I've created a form with two check boxs and one button. I added this code

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Bg1.txt As String = "C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Bg1.txt"

        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(Bg1.txt)

        TextBox1.Text = objReader.ReadToEnd

        objReader.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

to the button thinking it would open Bg1.txt when clicked but it's not working? Any ideas?

Comment: "Not working" is not an appropriate problem description.

Comment: You might also want to improve the topic to reflect your actual problem. Because if something is "simple", then you should really be able to figure it out yourself, and that you're having some kind of trouble is obvious by the mere fact that you're asking someone else, i.e. the people on this website.

Comment: Just to check: Did you just copy-paste the code or did you actually set the button's Click event?

Answer (score 1):

Simple textbox is one line.
You cannot create variables with name containing dot "."
Open designer (where you edit form) right click textbox and check multiline.

```
Dim TXTpath As String = "C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Bg1.txt"
Dim FileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
FileReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(TXTpath)
TextBox1.Text = FileReader.ReadToEnd()
FileReader.Close()
```

Comment: That doesn't open the file which is what the OP is expecting

Answer (score 0):

The thing that stands out the most to me is that you are using Bg1.Txt as a string name which is invalid. I have taken your code and modified it like this, and it does work.

```
Dim filename As String = "C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Bg1.txt"
Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(filename)
TextBox1.Text = objReader.ReadToEnd
objReader.Close()
```

Comment: The OP states "...thinking it would open Bg1.txt when clicked ..." that doesn't open the file, that just reads the contents into the textbox.

Comment: @AlfalfaStrange if you look at his code that is what he is doing.. reading it into a textbox. It doesn't appear that he wants to open it in Notepad which is what your code will do.

Comment: yes I see that, and he states,  "...thinking it would open Bg1.txt when clicked but it's not working..." He's expecting to see it open and is using the wrong way to try to open a file, he doesn't need to use the StreamReader to open a file.

Comment: @AlfalfaStrange you have to open a file to get the information out of it to put it into a TextBox which is what the StreamReader does. It is a matter of semantics, you are reading alot into his statement.. but only the OP knows what he means.